# centering issue in the multilevel modeling

Tags: multilevel-analysis, centering

I learned that categorical variable should be centered just like continuous variable.
I am analyzing two level model, (MLM).

case 1.

when the categorical variable is level 1 predictor, and have interaction within the level (interact with other level 1 predictor), group mean centering is not good choice?

Yaremych et al., (2021) recommend using cluster mean when categorical variable involves interactions. But I cannot understand the reason why.

case 2.

To my knowledge, level 2 predictor does not  have to be centered while level 1 predictor should be centered. But many people recommend, so I wonder why.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also, please edit the question to say where you learned that centering is needed at all, in particular please give a complete reference to Yaremych et al. Centering continuous predictors, although only necessary in applications like principal components analysis, can make interpretation of some coefficients easier. In extreme cases it can avoid numerical problems in situations where it's often done internally by software. But what do you mean by "centering" a categorical predictor?